# Crashing with observeForSingleEventOfType

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I've got this method:

```
func fetchImageWithKey(key: String, completion: UIImage -> ()) {
  imagesEndPoint.childByAppendingPath(key).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    guard let imageString = snapshot.value["imageString"] as? String else { return }
    guard let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: imageString, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters), image = UIImage(data: imageData) else { fatalError() }
    completion(image)
  })
}
```

Which is called each time a cell is dequeued in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. For some reason, whilst scrolling through the tableView, this line `guard let imageString = snapshot.value["imageString"] as? String else { return }` will hit the `else` block.

I made sure that the ref does indeed have the key "imageString" and a value of type String in the end. I'm thinking it has something to do with the tableView cell dequeueing, but I'm not sure how I might approach this problem.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure: snapshot.value  is dictionary.
You should check :

```
if let dic = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
            guard let imageString = dic["imageString"] as? String else { return }
            guard let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: imageString, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters), image = UIImage(data: imageData) else { fatalError() }
            completion(image)
        }else{
            //
        }
```